# Java Spring apache POI, store long number in excel without exponents

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi

I'm trying to insert the BigDecimal value in excel but it is storing as exponential value.

The value is storing as exponential value with below code:
i/p: 1234567891012.12
o/p: 1.23457E+12

```
cell = rowhead.createCell(cellnumberno++);
        cell.setCellStyle(wrapRightDataNoBottomCellStyle);
        cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(cellValue));
```

when i'm trying to insert value in excel with below, then i'm getting error like "Number is strored as string":
i/p: 1234567891012.12
o/p: 1234567891012.12 with exclamation mark

```
cell = rowhead.createCell(cellnumberno++);
        cell.setCellStyle(wrapRightDataNoBottomCellStyle);
        cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
```

Is there a way to remove this number is stored as text error from java code before entering value.

Formatting as below is working fine but i dont want to restrict the number after decimal.

```
   XSSFDataFormat format=wb.createDataFormat();
   wrapRightDataNoBottomCellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.00"));
   cell.setCellStyle(wrapRightDataNoBottomCellStyle);
   cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(cellValue));
```

I dont want to format the cell with something like this "0.00", is there a way where i can set cell format to text and then enter the value and still avoid the number as text error?

I want insert the long decimal like below in excel as a string by avoiding "number stored as text" error. 
Input       : 1234567891012.12222
Expected o/p: 1234567891012.122222

Please help me, any pointers would be of great help.

Comment: What cell formatted would you apply in Excel to get your number to be displayed as you'd want? And what happens if you apply that same format as a style in POI?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my ticket with formatting description "0.00". Could you please help me on how can i format the cell as string and insert the long decimal in excel. also is there anyway i can remove that "number is stored as text" error mark in excel from JAVA code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would never storing numeric values as text. The requirement having numeric cell content with as much decimal places as needed and not switching to exponential would be fulfilled using the number format `0.0##############`. Each `#` means: use this digit if needed. Digits before the decimal point are always showed if needed. So there only one `0` is necessary. The format means in whole: at least one digit before the decimal point and at least one decimal place but 15 further decimal places maximal if needed. `Excel` always stores floating point values only with up to 15 significant digits precision. Thats why more than 15 decimal places are not useful.

But if the requirement really is, storing numeric values as text, then this also is possible using the number format `@`. This is the "Text" number format. To avoiding "number stored as text" warning, the usage of [XSSFSheet.addIgnoredErrors](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#addIgnoredErrors-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IgnoredErrorType...-) is possible if the `Excel` is of type `XSSF`.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

public class ExcelStoreBigNumbers {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String valueInput = "123456789012.12345";

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  CellStyle style;
  DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
  Row row;
  Cell cell;

  //numeric cell value formatted having as much decimal places as needed
  style = workbook.createCellStyle();
  style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.0##############"));
  row = sheet.createRow(0);
  cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellStyle(style);
  cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(valueInput)); //precision only up to 15 significant digits

  //string cell value formatted as text
  style = workbook.createCellStyle();
  style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@"));
  row = sheet.createRow(1);
  cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellStyle(style);
  cell.setCellValue(valueInput);

  //avoiding "number stored as text" warning
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   ((XSSFSheet)sheet).addIgnoredErrors(new CellReference(cell), IgnoredErrorType.NUMBER_STORED_AS_TEXT);
  }

  sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelStoreBigNumbers.xlsx"));
  workbook.close(); 
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank You very much Axel Richter, your answer is very much helpful to me.